# Logic in Java \ android

Tags: java, android, logic

Hi guys thats my checking methode, but i can't deal with logic.
Name is working fine, but Age \ Weight \ Height are working in wrong way (when I'm expecting true it goes false).

I've tried a few times with more () but still I can't fix it. Please help me with that logic or if You have any better idea with checking out and showing message about wrong values in textviews. Atm Im trying with alert builder.

When i put into:  _Age 24 the if statement adds 10   (I wanted to add 10 when its below 9 and more than 70 or empty)
The same goes with rest variables and i can't find my logic mistake.

```
private String checkValue(){
    String x = "";
    int a = 0; // TRUE == 1 false == 0 NAME > AGE > HEIGHT > WEIGHT
    String name = textName.getText().toString();
    String _Age = textAge.getText().toString();
    String _Weight = textWeight.getText().toString();
    String _Height = textHeight.getText().toString();



    if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(name))                                                                                  a+=1;
    if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(_Age) || ((Integer.parseInt(_Age) > 9) && (Integer.parseInt(_Age) < 70 )))                  a+=10;
    if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(_Height) || ((Integer.parseInt(_Height) > 100) &&( Integer.parseInt(_Height) < 250)))       a+=100;
    if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(_Weight) || (( Double.parseDouble(_Weight) > 30 ) && (Double.parseDouble(_Weight) < 300)))   a+=1000;
    if (a==0) x="All right boss here's the answer for your awsome body";
    while (a>=1) {
        x += "Please fill the data: otherwise - I cannot help you out mate";
        if (a >= 1000){
            x += ("\n- Weight a= "+a+" parse int _Weight: " + Integer.parseInt(_Weight));
            a-=1000;
        }
        if (a >= 100){
            x += ("\n- Height a= "+a+" parse int _Height: " + Integer.parseInt(_Height));
            a-=100;
        }
        if (a >= 10){
            x += ("\n- Age a= "+a+" parse int _Age: " + Integer.parseInt(_Age));
            a-=10;
        }
        if (a >= 1) {
            x += "\n- Name";
            a -=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make the specific issue a little more clear and maybe format a little more? You have some variables hanging out there that look like they are about to fall off a cliff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple logic:

```
String errorString = "";
boolean validate = true;
if(!ageString.isEmpty() && !heightString.isEmpty() && !weightString.isEmpty()) {
    if(age < 9 || age > 70) {
        errorMessage += "Invalid age!";
        validate = false;
    }
    if(height < 100 || age > 250) {
        errorMessage += "Invalid height!";
        validate = false;
    }
    if(weight < 30 || weight > 300) {
        errorMessage += "Invalid weight!";
        validate = false;
    }
}
else {
    errorString = "No empty fields allowed!";
    validate = false;
}
if(validate) {
    //Do whatever you want
}
else return errorString;
```

Comment: but this one never checks if the textviews are empty?(I might be confused a bit and not read it right). Whenever they're empty my program crashes.

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: This is only the logic in readable code format. This code as is won't work. You've to do `TextView` to `String` to `Integer` conversions and check in between if the `strings are not empty`.

Comment: ok i'll try soon just gotta clear my head. Thx for trying and advise anyway!

Comment: I reframed the code. Hope it helps. The first if condition checks if they are empty or not

Comment: thanks a lot mate, working just fine. Simplifying is always great idea! :)
Just the variable typo but it's not a probl, big up !